# Append to an element inside a set of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append to an element inside a string. Can javascript do this?

I have edited my question for some reason

example:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    var trymeor = "<div class='me'><article><div class='special'></div></article></div>";
    console.log($(trymeor).find('.special').append('Hello, am testing'));
});
```

So that variable **tymeor** will now become like this:

```
var trymeor = "<div class='me'><article><div class='special'>Hello, am testing </div></article></div>";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are applying text to a node, you would the `text` function, if you wanted deal with html, you would use the `html` function.   The reason im hesitant on append is iteration, on subsequent runs not setting the data, but appending to what was already there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is the correct approach, but the DIV is the only element, and `find` finds descendant elements, so you just wanted

```js
var trymeor  = "<div class='me'></div>";
var $element = $(trymeor).text('Hello, am testing');
    
console.log( $element.get(0).outerHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you can create elements with jQuery as well

```
$('<div />', {'class' : 'me', text : 'Hello, am testing'})
```

If you want to access a root element with a selector, you can also use `filter`

```js
var trymeor = "<div class='me'></div>";
var $element = $(trymeor);

$element.filter('.me').text('Hello, am testing');

console.log($element.get(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to target both descendants and root elements, you can wrap your HTML is container

```js
var trymeor = "<div class='me'></div>";
var $element = $('<div />', {html : trymeor});

$element.find('.me').text('Hello, am testing');

console.log($element.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if var trymeor contains multiple div with special class and I want to append to a special element of class in the string?? cuz thats what I want to do

Comment: @lernyoung trymeor is just a string so you can't do dom manipulation on it; instead you can use the same method of creating elements with jQuery that @adeneo is showing you to create nested elements (so create `.me` first, then insert `.special`.

Comment: Now you've changed the question completely, and you've actually posted working code as you're now targeting descendant elements with `find`. If you just structure it a little differently you can see it working -> https://jsfiddle.net/14dprjoc/

Comment: its working but explain to me...why did you use the get() ...I learnt it is use to send data to server like :  
$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Comment: jQuery also has another [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method, that is used to get the underlying native DOM node, and as jQuery has no `outerHTML` I used `get(0)` to get the first *(and only)* DOM node in the collection so I could use `outerHTML` to get the string back and show that it was changed.

Comment: Thank you...that was brilliant !